# Definition of normal subgroup generated by subset in Artin’s Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

In the second edition of Michael Artin’s *Algebra* I find the following definition and lemma (7.10.3):

> Let $R$ be a subset of a group $G$. There exists a unique smallest normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ that contains $R$, called the *normal subgroup generated by $R$* […] The elements of $N$ can be described in either of the following ways:
>
> 1. An element of $G$ is in $N$ if it can be obtained from elements of $R$ using a finite sequence of the operations of multiplication, inversion, and conjugation.
> 2. […]

The proof says that such an $N$ is closed under those operations and is therefore normal. But that isn’t enough, is it? How do I know that $ghg^{-1}$ is in $N$ for **arbitrary** $g \in G$ and $h \in N$? Before I read the proof I wondered why conjugation is explicitly mentioned in (1) since multiplication and inversion is enough to also be able to conjugate. Then the claim in the proof of $N$ being closed under conjugation makes me think that what is meant in (1) is conjugation by any element of $G$ not merely $R$. Then it would also make sense to mention conjugation in the first place. Am I missing something or did Artin forget to add “by any element of $G$” at the end of (1)?

Comment: It clearly means $G$-conjugation, but a careful author would have made that explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: when Artin writes “conjugation” in (1), he means conjugation by arbitrary elements of $G$.